# retrieve sql data & print it into form field

Tags: php, ajax

here is an example that if i enter id then it will retrieve data from database & print it within form fields. my database has only three column- id, name & number. here is my index.html file:

```
    <html>

<head>

    <script>

        function showData(str)
        {
            if (str=="")
            {
                document.getElementById("ajax-content").innerHTML="";
                return;
            } 

            // Code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
            {
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            }

            // Code for IE6, IE5
            else
            {
                xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }

            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
            {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                {
                    document.getElementById("ajax-content").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }

            xmlhttp.open("GET","showData.php?id="+str,true);

            xmlhttp.send();

        }
        return true;

    </script>

</head>

<body>


    <p>Please Enter Your Staff ID:</p>
    <div><input onkeyup="if (event.keyCode == 13) showData(this.value); return false;" /></div>



<div id="ajax-content"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

and here is my showData.php file:

```
    <?php

    // Receive variable from URI
    $id=$_GET["id"];

    // Connect to your database
    $con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
    if (!$con)
    {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    // Select your database
    mysql_select_db("test_01", $con);

    // Select all fields from your table
    $sql="SELECT * FROM staffdetails WHERE id = '".$id."'";

    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {

        echo "Staff Name:" . "<input type='text' value='" . $row['name'] . "'>";
        echo "</br>";
        echo "Contact No.:" . "<input type='text' value='" . $row['number'] . "'>";
    }

    // Close the connection
    mysql_close($con);

?>
```

now what i'm trying to do is, display the data in a given form field rather than print data with the form field. that means, the name & number input field will be already in the form with the id field. when i'll enter id then it will pull back the data & display it in the given form field. anyone can help please? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's a javascript error in your index.html page. The `return true` statment should be inside function brackets.

Also try adding **document type** and **content type** on top of index.html page to show text fields instead of printing it.

Hope this will help solving your problem.